# substitute LHS in `=` operator with rlang tidyeval inside Sys.setenv

Tags: r, metaprogramming, rlang, tidyeval, pryr

**Problem description**

`Sys.setenv` does not have an easy interface to supply LHS (the env var name) as a parameter. If one wants to dynamically define what env var should be set, then metaprogramming approach is required.

**Base R way**

This small helper function works as expected.

```r
setenv = function(var, value, quiet=TRUE) {
  stopifnot(is.character(var), !is.na(var), length(value)==1L, is.atomic(value))
  qc = as.call(c(list(quote(Sys.setenv)), setNames(list(value), var)))
  if (!quiet) print(qc)
  eval(qc)
}

var_name = "RISCOOL"
Sys.getenv(var_name)
#[1] ""
setenv(var_name, value=150, quiet=FALSE)
#Sys.setenv(RISCOOL = 150)
Sys.getenv(var_name)
#[1] "150"
```

**Question**

The question is about how the problem can be solved using packages like [`pryr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pryr) or [`rlang`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rlang) ([`tidyeval`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyeval))? or eventually another popular one.
I don't know these packages at all and would like to get better understanding how they could simplify my metaprogramming code.

Note that question is about metaprogramming, setting env var is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use rlang-style quasiquotation to construct a call and directly evaluate, you need `blast()`

```
blast <- function(expr, env = caller_env()) {
  eval_bare(enexpr(expr), env)
}

vars <- c(A = "a", B = "b", C = "c")

blast(data.frame(!!!vars))
#>   A B C
#> 1 a b c
```

In your original example you need to unquote a name. We don't support deep-unquoting on the LHS of `:=` yet (see https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/279), but you can use `!!!` instead:

```
setenv <- function(var, value) {
  args <- setNames(value, var)
  blast(Sys.setenv(!!!args))
}

setenv("foobar", 1)
#> [1] TRUE

Sys.getenv("foobar")
#> [1] "1"
```

To insert the printed call, blast is too high level but you can use the components:

```
setenv <- function(var, value, quiet = FALSE) {
  args <- setNames(value, var)
  call <- expr(Sys.setenv(!!!args))

  if (!quiet) {
    print(call)
  }

  # Evaluate in our own environment where `Sys.setenv()` is defined
  # (and protected if we're in a package namespace)
  eval(call)
}
```

Comment: seems to be what I was looking for, but your example could match to the one in the question.

Comment: I have added `setenv()` examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use `do.call`:

```
var_name = "RISCOOL"
do.call("Sys.setenv", as.list(setNames(3, var_name)))

# check that it worked
Sys.getenv(var_name)
## [1] "3"
```

or using purrr

```
library(purrr)
invoke("Sys.setenv", set_names(4, var_name))
```

Comment: It might be nicer base R way, but the question is about `rlang` or `pryr` which I would like to understand better. I actually prefer to have an option to print a call before evaluating it, and this is not doable for `do.call`.

Comment: Creating a call and then evaluating it at runtime is not very good programming practice. It means you have to have all of R available at runtime to do the eval.  If you must do it with tidyverse use invoke from purrr and set_names from rlang.  I have added this to answer.

Comment: "you have to have all of R available at runtime to do the eval" - I don't understand this. It doesn't have to be tidyverse way, but some popular package for metaprogramming, to see how it can help in tasks like this. purrr example is another one nice method for that. Thanks

Comment: If the problem requires `eval` then of course use it but if you can avoid it you should.

Comment: eval is invoked anyway by `do.call` just not explicitly with `eval` function, isn't it?

Comment: but I don't get why that difference matters?

Comment: Imagine that R were compiled. Then `do.call` would only need a runtime that included the function invoked by `do.call` but `eval` would need all of R.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `:=`.
Its usage is explained in one of the [`dplyr` vignettes](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html),
but the functionality is provided by `rlang`.
In this case you can use `call2`:

```
setenv <- function(var, val) {
  rlang::call2("Sys.setenv", !!rlang::enexpr(var) := val)
}

setenv(foo, "bar")
# Sys.setenv(foo = "bar")
```

Just add an `eval` call as desired.

Comment: AFAIU this will not work without wrapping `call2` call in the extra function?

Comment: @jangorecki it won't evaluate without the extra `eval`, I left it out just to show the constructed call.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `do.call`.

```r
lst <- structure(list(value), names=name)
do.call(Sys.setenv, lst)
```

Comment: It might be nicer base R way, but the question is about `rlang`or `pryr` which I would like to understand better. I actually prefer to have an option to print a call before evaluating it, and this is not doable for `do.call`.